# is it possible the flutter call the existing app function

Tags: flutter

I have read the official document.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=ios-channel-objective-c-tab
This is not what I want.

I have done the flutter to add to existing iOS app.
Now I want to use flutter to call the existing iOS app function.

Like below, I want to in my_flutter to call MyApp native code.

my_flutter/
│   └── .ios/
│       └── Flutter/
│         └── podhelper.rb
└──

MyApp/
└── Podfile

Does it possible realize?
Thanks.

When I set the method channel in existing iOS project. It crashed.
The error messages are;

-[CustomNavigationViewController setMessageHandlerOnChannel:binaryMessageHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107009200

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomNavigationViewController setMessageHandlerOnChannel:binaryMessageHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107009200'

Comment: please try this  article :- https://medium.com/47billion/creating-a-bridge-in-flutter-between-dart-and-native-code-in-java-or-objectivec-5f80fd0cd713

Comment: first you can try to make *APP FUNCTION* a separate module, then you can use it in Flutter app